# Use "operator T*()" instead of "T* operator->()" for member access

Tags: c++, syntax, type-conversion

The expression `x->y` requires `x` to be a pointer to complete class type, or when `x` is an instance of a class, requires `operator->()` defined for `x`. But when the latter is the case, why *not* can I use conversion function instead (i.e., convert object `x` to a pointer)? For example:

```
struct A
{
    int mi;

    operator A*() { return this; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    a[1];  // ok: equivalent to *(a.operator A*() + 1);
    a->mi; // ERROR
}
```

This gives an error message:

`error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'A'`

But the question is, why don't it use `a.operator A*()` instead, just like `a[1]` does ?

Comment: `*(a.operator A*() + 1)` is not equivalent to `a[1]` in your example.

Comment: Hi @Axalo, I have no idea yet what is wrong here, could you please point it out? thx

Comment: `a.operator A*()` results in a pointer to `a.`Therefore `*(a.operator A*() + 1)` will result in `*(&a + 1)`. On the other hand, `a[1]` returns a. And `a != *(&a + 1)`.

Comment: @Axalo "On the other hand, a[1] returns a" - no it doesn't. You perhaps are not seeing the "#if 0 ... #endif" pair.

Comment: @davmac If the code should be ignored it shouldn't be in the question. I advise an edit to prevent future misunderstandings.

Comment: @Axalo there's no point in advising _me_ of that. Take it up with the OP.

Comment: @davmac That wasn't my intention. It was more like a hint to the OP.

Comment: I wish I could upvote edits. Thanks Barry.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the special overload resolution rules for operators in expressions. For most operators, if either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, operator functions and built-in operators compete with each other, and overload resolution determines which one is going to be used. This is what happens for `a[1]`. However, there are some exceptions, and the one that applies to your case is in paragraph [13.3.1.2p3.3] in the standard (emphasis mine in all quotes):

> (3.3) — For the operator `,`, the unary operator `&`, or the operator `->`,
>   *the built-in candidates set is empty*. For all other operators, the
>   built-in candidates include all of the candidate operator functions
>   defined in 13.6 that, compared to the given operator,
>
> - have the same operator name, and
> - accept the same number of operands, and
> - accept operand types to which the given operand or operands can be converted according to 13.3.3.1, and
> - do not have the same parameter-type-list as any non-member candidate that is not a function template specialization.

So, for `a[1]`, the user-defined conversion is used to get a pointer to which the built-in `[]` operator can be applied, but for the three exceptions up there, only operator functions are considered first (and there aren't any in this case). Later on, [13.3.1.2p9]:

> If the operator is the operator `,`, the unary operator `&`, or the
>   operator `->`, *and there are no viable functions*, then the operator is
>   assumed to be the built-in operator and interpreted according to
>   Clause 5.

In short, for these three operators, the built-in versions are considered only if everything else fails, and then they have to work on the operands without any user-defined conversions.

As far as I can tell, this is done to avoid confusing or ambiguous behaviour. For example, built-in operators `,` and `&` would be viable for (almost) all operands, so overloading them wouldn't work if they would be considered during the normal step of overload resolution.

Operator `->` has an unusual behaviour when overloaded, as it can result in a chain of invocations of overloaded `->`, as explained in [note 129]:

> If the value returned by the `operator->` function has class type, this
>   may result in selecting and calling another `operator->` function. The
>   process repeats until an `operator->` function returns a value of
>   non-class type.

I suppose the possibility that you'd start from a class that overloads `->`, which returns an object of another class type, which doesn't overload `->` but has a user-defined conversion to a pointer type, resulting in a final invocation of the built-in `->` was considered a bit too confusing. Restricting this to explicit overloading of `->` looks safer.

---

All quotes are from N4431, the current working draft, but the relevant parts haven't changed since C++11.

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted to know about, thanks for your accurate and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the standard to hand, perhaps someone can come in and present a better answer after me. However, from the narrative on cppreference.com:

> The left operand of the built-in operator. and operator-> is an expression of complete scalar type T (for operator.) or pointer to complete scalar type T* (for operator->), which is evaluated before the operator can be called. The right operand is the name of a member object or member function of T or of one of T's base classes, e.g. expr.member, optionally qualified, e.g. expr.name::member, optionally using template disambiguator, e.g. expr.template member.
>   The expression A->B is exactly equivalent to (*A).B for builtin types. **If a user-defined operator-> is provided, operator-> is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until the operator-> is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, builtin semantics are applied to that pointer.**

Emphasis is mine.

If operator -> is to be called recursively on the result of another operator -> (which will have a pointer return type), it strongly implies that operator -> must be called on a pointer type.

Comment: I think you're misreading that somehow.  "If operator -> is to be called recursively on the result of another operator -> (which will have a pointer return type)" - there is no requirement that `operator ->` will have a pointer return type. The section you quoted specifically explains what happens in this case.